# How to remove blank page caused by long list tabular

Tags: tables, lists, blank-page

I have searched and read related post in the forum, but didn´t find a solution which can make the blank page disappear. I have used

```
  \nopagebreak[0]
```

before, and it worked, but I dont know why it doesnt work anymore when I have changed my print type to oneside from twoside.

=======================================================

I know where the blank page comes out, and it can be removed by delete one line in "List of Abbreviations", but I still need all the information. Is there a way to get away the blank page but also keep all the information in List of Abbreviations?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline,DIV=12,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times new roman font
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=numeric,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{scrpage2}     
\pagestyle{scrheadings}   
\clearscrheadfoot         
\automark[section]{chapter}   
\ohead{\pagemark}              
\ihead{\headmark}           
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{roman}   
\chapter{Abstract}
\blindtext
\nopagebreak[0]
\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\  
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
 \end{tabular}%
 \label{tab:addlabel}%
 \lipsum[1-0]
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}    
 \tableofcontents
 \clearpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic} 
 \chapter{Chapter1}
 \blindtext
 \pagenumbering{roman}  
 \setcounter{page}{10}
 \end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `\include` does not force a blank page.

Comment: An example would be needed, but I don't think that `\include` for the list of abbreviations and the abstract is the right tool to use: `\input` is much easier and less troublesome.

Comment: You may soon have the need to compiler your individual `*.tex` files individually for performance reasons, especially if they contain pictures. Therefore you should start using the `{subfiles}` package right away.  refer to this answer for details: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347721/compiling-multiple-latex-files/347732#347732

Comment: @TimothyTruckle why? the whole point of `\include` is that it allows chapters to be processed one at a time if needed. No extra package is needed for that.

Comment: I have tried with \input, there is still this blank page . I dont know where it comes from...@egreg

Comment: You should probably consider using a `longtable` rather than a regular `tabular` for your abbreviations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The downside of `\include` is, that you have to *comment all other chapters/sections* and run LaTeX against the *main* document. And things get worse if you go down the hirarchy and separate (sub-)sections in their own files too...  With the `{subfiles}` package you don't need to change anything in in any of the files to compile a single one. Just invoke LaTeX on the desired. I for myself found that this simpified my workflow...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle "comment"???? No please read the documentation of `\includeonly`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\includeonly` eases the pain a little but I still have to change the document and compile against the main file. But anyway, I wonder why you argue agains the alternative of `{subfiles}` package, nobody forces you to use it...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle With a decent editor, you don't have to "change the document", because the editor automatically recognises the main file. *Cought*, TeXStudio, *Cought*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to squeeze one more line onto a page, you can use `\enlargethispage{}`. If you have more entries that will be added, you should look into tables that break over pages, e.g. `longtable`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline,DIV=12,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx} %times new roman font
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
        style=numeric,natbib=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{scrpage2}     
\pagestyle{scrheadings}   
\clearscrheadfoot         
\automark[section]{chapter}   
\ohead{\pagemark}              
\ihead{\headmark}           
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{13pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{roman}   
\chapter{Abstract}
\blindtext
\nopagebreak[0]
\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\enlargethispage{1em}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\  
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
ABS   & Anti-lock Brake System \\ 
 \end{tabular}%
 \label{tab:addlabel}%
 \lipsum[1-0]
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}    
 \tableofcontents
 \clearpage
% \pagenumbering{arabic} 
 \chapter{Chapter1}
 \blindtext
 \end{document}
```

Comment: @Vivian With a MWE to start with your problem could have been solved hours ago. But you made the users here spend their time trying to guess a solution based on entirely wrong information.

Comment: I can´t reproduce the error in the begining , and I thought the problem was \include function which braught the blank page. Otherwise I would provide the MWE earlier. I am aware that the other users can help me better with the MWE. I´m sorry for what has happened.  It also takes me very long time before I found out where the problem really is.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use `\input` instead of `\include` since it doesn't contain a `\pagebreak` you shouldn't have your blank page problem.

Comment: in most classes `\chapter` forces a new page anyway so `\include` does not introduce any extra page breaks.

Comment: You're right but `\include` contain a `\pagebreak` which can behave like a page break on odd-numbered pages. And since `\input` is more low-level it can spare the disconfort that that.

Comment: No. `\chapter` will force one or two new pages depending on the parity of the current page.  If each  `\include`  starts with `\chapter` you will just have the same page breaks as using `\chapter` directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried with \input, there is still this blank page . I dont know where it comes from...

Comment: I have found out the reason why a blank page appear between list of abbreviation and abstract. Because the content in list of abbreviation is quite long and it almost reach the edge of the page, so that  the whole page has been moved one page down in order to keep enough space between. Is there a way to keep the content in abbreviation but also avoid this blank page?  @DavidCarlisle